# Cannot open edit or save file with Python IDLE [Errno 22] Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, errno

I am trying to open a .py file with IDLE which is located suppose:

C:\Users\символ\Desktop\file.py

I get the following error:
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:

C:\Users\?????\Desktop\file.py

If I put file.py at C:\Users\New Folder\file.py
It opens up just fine. Tried adding UTF-8 encoding
and saved it this way. Did not seemed to work.

Comment: Could you try opening a file with IDLE of Python3? Also, which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I found the problem

Clock, Language, and Region -> Language Options -> Administrative -> Change system locale...-> Russia

If it is set to "USA" it will not read russian letters..
So now I'm just wondering if there is a fix to it by code? or it is a windows problem..

Comment: Well, it is partially a Windows problem. I am not aware of the details in-depth, but it looks like that instead of using UTF-8 for paths, it is using e.g. Win1251 for Russian. Thus, the characters are simply not recognized by Python (because it has no idea, which encoding it should use) when you are in 'USA' locale.

Comment: Maybe if i include locale.getlocale() code inside that .py file it will find the path and open it while windows is using "USA" Locale?